# Androidアプリ開発でのXMLのエラーに関しての質問です

Tags: android, java, android-layout, xml

現在XMLファイルとJavaファイルを編集しています．
XMLでのエラー処理ができません．

エラーの場所は一行目の

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

です．

エラー表示として，

この行で見つかった複数の注釈:
    - "[xX][mM][lL]" と一致する処理命令ターゲットは使
     用できません。
    - エラー: Error parsing XML: junk after 
     document element

また，以下にコードを記載します．

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_root" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fillparent"
        android:layout_height="fillparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TabWidget
        android:layout_width="fillparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"></TabWidget>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contentlayout1">
    </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: (1)`<tabHost` と `</TabHost>` がマッチしてません。おそらく、`<TabHost`の間違い。 (2)  `android:id="@+id/tabhost` の最後が「"」で閉じてません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．確かに間違っていました．
しかし，その二か所の修正は行ったのですが，同じ部分でエラーが直りません．
他の対策あれば教えてほしいです．

Comment: 私のコメント時既に回答されていたのでコメントしてませんでしたが、ＸＭＬ文書は文書のフォーマットとして`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`で始まる必要がある（エラーメッセージはそのことが理由だと思われます）ので一行目の`<!-- language: lang-xml -->`は削除してみて下さい。

Comment: すみません．<LinearLaout>を記載するのを忘れていたので再度書き直しました．
また<!-- language: lang-xml -->も削除しましたがエラーがまだなおりません．
よろしくお願いします．

Comment: `RelativeLayout` タグを追加されたようですが、繰り返しになりますが`<?xml ...`  より後に書く必要があります。また、対応する閉じタグが無いように思います。

Comment: エラーメッセージに変化はないですか？また他のエラーメッセージは出ていませんか？

Answer (score 1):

XML宣言（`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`）は、ファイルの先頭にある必要があり、前にコメントを入れることはできません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．
大変恐縮ですが，アプリ開発関して初心者ですので「前にコメントを入れることはできません」といわれてもどういうことなのかいまいちわかりません．
具体的に，何をすることができなくて，何をすると良いのか等の回答をいただきたいと思います．